# What type of filter did I accidentally create here?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, low-pass, sallen-key

I was trying to make a low-pass Sallen-Key filter, but I messed it up and made something else. I already have my PCB, so no going back now! I need to tune the cut-off frequency, but I don't know how the cut-off frequency would be calculated here. Can someone help me calculate the cut-off frequency for this filter?

What I made:

[image: Filter!]

A real Sallen-Key filter:

[image: Real Filter]

Comment: Consider that R8 in your circuit does effectively nothing.

Comment: People get PWBs wrong all the time and modify them as needed. Does your design use thru-hole parts or SMTs? There are There are different techniques for each.

Comment: My simulation shows it's a like a 1st order low-pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

The current through \$R_{8}\$ is zero so the voltage \$V_{\text C5}=V_{\text out}\$. Therefore \$V_{\text C2}=0\$. So  \$R_{8}\$ and \$C_{2}\$ do nothing. You have a \$1^{\text st}\$ order low pass filter with a corner frequency:

$$\omega_{c}=\frac{1}{R_{7}C_{5}}$$

Depending on routing to turn it back into a Sallen-Key, C5 can be rewired by hand.

Update: LvW is right in the comments. \$C_{2}\$ is in series with \$R_{8}\$ across the inputs which does affect performance. If the filter is to be used as a \$1^{\text st}\$ order filter, then perhaps \$C_{2}\$ should not be installed.

Comment: "C2 does nothing" is not quite correct. It provides external frequency compensation (loop gain reduction) and improves stability of the unity gain opamp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - as it was already mentioned, the circuit resembles a 1st-order lowpass (3dB- cut off at wc=1/R7C5).

So - the question arises "what do the two other componenets do?".

- The resistor R8 has practically no influence because the opamps input resistance is extremely high (due to 100% negative feedback). Therefore, no curent through R8.
- As a consequence, the capacitor C2 can be seen as a component between both opamp terminals. It can be shown that - even for a non-ideal (real) opamp - such a component will not influence the closed-loop gain.
  However, the capacitor C2 will directly influence the loop gain and will improve the stability margin of the unity gain amplifier. It provides a kind of "external frequency compensation".

Comment: Compensation for what problem? If the amp is already stable, what is the benefit?

Comment: For any opamp based gain stage - and in particular, for a unity gain stage - the question is not simply "stable or not" but "how stable"? That means - what is the stability margin? In many cases, we require that the phase margin is larger than 60 deg. because smaller margins cause a step response with ringing. Therefore, in some cases, we use some additional means for improving the stability margin. I have mentioned this point only because I could read here that C2 would have "no effect" - and this is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need is a fairly small correction.  C5 is connected to the wrong side of R8.

Cut the trace from C5 to R8.  Cut it close to C5.  Use a sharp knife point (scalpel, x-acto knife, pointed pocket knife blade, etc.) and check with an ohmmeter to be sure the connection is really broken.

Solder a fine wire from C5 to the other side of R8.  Insulated wire is best - wire wrapping wire is good, but you may not have any or be able to get it quickly.  You can also use a single strand out of a short piece of stranded wire - pull the insulation off the wire then separate out one of the strands.

If you use an uninsulated strand, you'll have to arrange it so that it can't cause a short circuit.  A spot of cyanoacrylate glue (super glue) could be used to hold it in place - but don't heat the wire when the glue is on it as the fumes are quite nasty.